# How to calculate "kleinster gemeinsamer Nenner" Last common denominator

Tags: .net, algorithm, math

I could not find anything because of my English perhaps. I want to find the smallest dividing value of several numbers.
In German it is called: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptnenner
I want to know how to do this in .Net because I cannot believe that this question is new and have not found a solution except to do it like on paper to count the "2 dividers and 3 dividers".

Would be great to get any advice.

Regards

Comment: Wikipedia links to the English definition as "lowest common denominator": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_denominator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website already tells you how to do it: Find the least common multiple for the set of all denominators. You can exploit the relation between least common multiple and greatest common divisor (see Wikipedia) and simply use the Euclidean algorithm (also available on Wikipedia).

Schau nach, wie du den ggT (groessten gemeinsamen Teiler berechnest -> Euklids Algorithmus). Danach kannst du den Hauptnenner aus dem kgV der Nenner berechnen.

Answer (score 1):

The Least Common Denominator is usually called the Least Common Multiplier LCM. There is a relation between LCM of two numbers a and b, denoted L(a, b), and the Greatest Common Divisor GCD(a, b) of these numbers:

```
LCM(a, b) = a * b / GCD(a, b)
```

The GCD(a, b) can be computed very efficiently using the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Further, the computation of LCM for three numbers can be reduced to LCM of two numbers:

```
LCM(a, b, c) = LCM(LCM(a, b), c),
```

and hence again to computation of GCD of two numbers. Now, the procedure to compute LCM for N numbers should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because of your example I understood immediately how to solve right now. Because Michaell answered in German before, I allow me to give him the answer hook. Hope its ok. I am just happy that it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Jiri showed how LCM and GCD reduce to computing the GCD of two numbers. Jeff's algorithm is too slow for large numbers. Here's the sketch of an algorithm that's polynomial in the length of the input numbers, call them X and Y:

- set result = 1
- if both X and Y are even, result *=2; X /= 2; Y /=2;
- if one is even, the other odd, half the one that's even (nothing else gets updated)
- if both are odd, subtract the smaller from the larger and iterate (note this gives us an even-odd combination

proof of the polynomial complexity comes from the fact that in every two iterations, we reduce at least one of the numbers by at least half

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar to this and came up with this solution.  Most solutions I found were for two numbers and my solution needed to handle an unknown quantity of numbers. Anyway, this is what I came up with.  It works for me, and perhaps it will work for you.

```
    public static int GetLCM(int[] values) {
        var retval = values[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < values.Length; i++) {
            retval = GCD(retval, values[i]);
        }
        return retval;
    }
    private static int GCD(int val1, int val2) {
        while (val1 != 0 && val2 != 0) {
            if (val1 > val2) 
                val1 %= val2;
            else 
                val2 %= val1;
        }
        return System.Math.Max(val1,val2);
    }
```

Comment: this is a brute force algorithm, has very poor complexity (will take ~2^31 steps for two 32 bit ints that are close to Integer.MAX_VALUE) see my suggestions below